# Inverted border-radius?

Tags: css

Given this simple plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/aTM80EUHAYds1h5TIXTh?p=preview

I would like to be able to be able to have a `border-radius` on the inner corner between the two divs (the only sharp corner on this example). I added a `div#corner` (currently on `display:none`) that could do the trick, but I have really no idea how (and if it's even possible) to have an inverted `border-radius`.

How could I get that effect without using an image?

**edit**

[Here is](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Hc9nr?p=preview) a better, more flexible way of doing it, thanks to @Colandus for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a gray square with the length of the radius you want there, and then put a white rounded div (circle) on top of it, the div having the width twice the length of the gray square.

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RxMMvqS74aMq018P5Jsq?p=preview (I reused your corner div, and added a circle div on top)

Experiment with the width/height of the corner and circle divs and the circle div's radius to get different rounding effects.

Here is a more rounded version: http://plnkr.co/edit/uwRZHCzAxEcQSQ2Elu6u?p=preview

Comment: Very nice! Works like a charm! I updated my plunkr, now shows the correct result (original problem still visible in older revisions). Thank you

Comment: It can be made more flexible using `:before` and `:after` in the place of `#corner` and `#circle`  and also `background: inherit` on the `#corner`

Comment: @Colandus How would you do it? I never really used :after and :before, I'm not sure how to implement this

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9NdPelJIym7XqjakdJqu?p=preview Here's an example. They are pretty much like adding a `div` in the normal way, and styling it. So you just need to pretend it's a `div` that's after/before it (except it's not a block-element by default, so you can pretend it's a `span` rather). The only difference when it comes to styling is that it requires `content`. As we don't want to display any letters we use a blank content.

Comment: Thank you, very clear now! I just wish there was a way to avoid defining the style explicitly for `#div1:after` and `#div1:before`... Here is something I tried : http://plnkr.co/edit/9Hc9nr?p=preview

What do you think? You only have to set `#div1:after`'s `border-radius` to something between 0 and 12px

Comment: Well the point of mine was that you wouldn't need to have the same definitions all over again on the different sides. You should only need to change top/left/bottom/right. That's why I gave the shared attributes to the main #div. You could separate them by a comma though... http://plnkr.co/edit/9NdPelJIym7XqjakdJqu?p=preview

Comment: Good point, @Colandus! Glad I could help, Samuel, you're welcome. :)